# Silverlight Toolkit, Where do you put the binaries

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

So you download the toolkit off Codeplex.  Now what?  Where do you prefer to place the binaries?

I'm particularly interested in what you do with the design binaries, where in your systems folders do you place these?  Do you add them to the GAC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question definitely targets the original release(s) of the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). The March 2009, July 2009, and all future releases have this improved experience, so you won't need to copy the binaries into your project directories.

Starting earlier this year, we've updated the Silverlight Toolkit to have an MSI-based installer for Windows that does a number of tasks, including

- Create a set of folders under the Silverlight SDK, to contain the toolkit
- Create a Start Menu group with links to documentation, online forums, a getting started guide, and the source code
- Register the Silverlight Toolkit's controls with Visual Studio's toolbox and Expression Blend's control library
- Register the binaries as extensions, so that you can include a simple reference inside your projects

  ```
  <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit" />
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the updated.  Blend 2 still has a problem with the depth of the path to the DataVisualisation dll.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Blend 3 fixed it, I wish there would have been a way to get that out earlier. Somehow we create the longest assembly names ever!!

Comment: One issue I noticed was that on x64 systems, the binaries are installed in Program Files (x86).  This can be an issue if you're sharing the projects between 32-bit and 64-bit systems.

Comment: x64 should not come into play here, since the reference does not include an actual path - don't just add a reference by browsing for the file, but instead it will show up in the .NET add reference dialog just fine. Also, if MsBuilding from the command line, it's common practice to use the 32-bit VS command prompt window for that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just put them somewhere convenient, then add references to them in my projects, using Browse in the Add Reference dialog.
I'd certainly not put them in the GAC.

Comment: FYI: There's no GAC for the Silverlight platform, so that's very good advice to not install them there.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the toolkit.

With every different solution you have, create folders "Foreign/[Name]" ("Foreign/Silverlight Toolkit" in this case) in your root solution directory. Copy the required dll-s there and then reference them from the project in question.

If you want to modify the toolkit, then you can add part of the source code as a project to your solution, and reference that in the other projects that use it.

Adding the modified toolkit to a separate solution might be a good idea for easier reuse.

Answer (score 0):

[Adding Silverlight to the GAC](http://templatereactor.com/blog/adding-silverlight-to-the-gac.html)

The solution turned out to be quite straight-forward.  Hope this helps.